# Считать размер ID3v2 тегов из mp3 файла (Java, побитовые операции)

Tags: java, id3v2

Как можно считать размер тегов из ID3v2 заголовка с помощью Java?

Вкратце:
Размер хранится в 4 байтах[6,7,8,9 байты от начала]. Из 8 бит используется 7, первый бит всегда 0. Пример из статьи на хабре [image: Пример расположения байт ID3v2]
Убираем пустые байты, затем убираем нули из 3го байта и первый ноль из последнего остаётся [][][111][1110110]. Теперь объединяем получившееся и получаем искомое число. Только, как это сделать в коде?

Может кому пригодится:
Ссылка на статью на хабре: [Внутри MP3. А как оно всё устроено?](https://habr.com/ru/post/103635/)
Ссылка на описание структуры ID3: [Структура ID3 с офф сайта](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем как то так получилось. Не уверен на счёт маски... Надеюсь на комментарий более разбирающегося в вопросе.

```js
/**
         * Считывает значение int из 4 байт, отбрасывая 0 бит из каждого байта
         * @param fourByte 4 байта числа
         * @return Число
         */
        private int bytesToSynchsafeInt(byte[] fourByte){
            return (((fourByte[0] & 0xff) << 21) | (((fourByte[1] & 0xff) << 14) |
                    (((fourByte[2] & 0xff) <<  7) | ((fourByte[3] & 0xff)))));
        }
```

P.S.
Кстати, к размеру ещё надо добавить 10 байт заголовка